# Dockerfile : How to pass en variable in runtime to Entrypoint array

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

I ve a dockerized app , based on **java** jar.

*My **Dockerfile** looks like this :*

```
FROM jdk:1.8.181 
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Dfile.encoding=utf-8", "-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError","-Xms256m","-Xmx256m", "-XshowSettings:vm","-jar","/opt/application/myapp.jar", "--spring.profiles.active=server"]
```

as you can see i'm passing  `"Xms256m","-Xmx256m"` as arguments to the **Entrypoint**

My purpose is to replace this to Runtime when running container ,

i'm using **docker-compose** :

```
myAppService:
  environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx12g -Xms12g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m #-> this doesn't work since JAVA_OPTS is not an env var
```

My Goal is to pass Xms and Xmx to the jar at runtime (while starting container ) not when generating image

**Suggestions ??**

Comment: the environment which you use will be used in the runtime not the build time . how do you know that is not working ?

Comment: which tells tje jdk that this variable JAVA_OPTS shoudl be used with java -jar command ?

Comment: I think it will read it by default

Comment: @LinPy is there anyway to display the the trace of thos jvm values ?

Comment: login to your container with `exec` and run `ps -ef | grep java` you should see the values

Comment: @LinPy there is no way to externalize this trace within docker logs ?